# Why would IE/MSN Messenger not be able to connect to anything, but firefox is fine?

Tags: internet-explorer, troubleshooting, internet-connection

My internet is fine.  I can connect to anything through firefox, but MSN Messenger and IE (IE8) are unable to connect to anything.  It's as if I don't have internet when I use them.  Why might this be?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a proxy setting applied for IE and MSN but not for Firefox? Or maybe a firewall setting?

Comment: no firewall, no proxies

Comment: not even windows firewall?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen occasions where IE has special settings that keep it from finding the internet. One place to look is Tools -> Internet Options -> Connections tab. Check everything there. Although I have no knowledge of it, it would seem likely to me that MSN uses IE's connection settings.